# MagicalRecord CoreData crash when saving the model: NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID expecting entity

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

When I call `mr_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()` I am getting errors in some cases. I cannot find the issue, I have been looking and playing around with it for quite a long time now.

Verbose logging gives me the following:

```
2017-08-24 12:12:55.166063+0100 trustedfamily-ios[35906:2870101] [error] error: oid = 0xd0000000054c0020 x-coredata://79D4E1A0-5016-4D96-84B0-4AF1002799A4/Document/p339 [oid class] = _NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID expecting entity Survey
CoreData: error: oid = 0xd0000000054c0020 x-coredata://79D4E1A0-5016-4D96-84B0-4AF1002799A4/Document/p339 [oid class] = _NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID expecting entity Survey
```

There are three entities in my Core Data Model that are involved in this crash.

1. **Event**: There is an entity **Event**, which is more or less a calendar event.
2. **Survey**: This event has a 1 to 1 relation to an entity **Survey**
3. **Document**: To an event you can attach multiple documents (1 to many relationship from the entity Event to the entity **Document**)

The entities Document and Survey have no direct relationship with each other.

Nevertheless the error says something about the entity Document is expecting entity Survey.
I am not understanding this error and don't know where to go from here at this point.

Comment: Document Do you have anywhere in your code where you use a Document entity when the api expected a Survey entity?

Comment: No, I don't -as far as I know-... I am wondering if it is something with the way I set up the model. Especially because it happens when I perform the save action. So this happens for example when the app goes in the background..

Comment: @JonRose Can you elaborate a bit more your comment above? Not gone anywhere yet with this issue yet. Maybe if I understand your comment a bit better it would guide me somewhere. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm just looking at the log which says that at some point it was expecting a survey entity, but got something else. I would check the assignment of the relationships. But I'm not sure that I am interpreting the error correctly